# Parsing json string of format {"rData":{"details":"abc123|val1|8de92ce|Item 1|val4"}

Tags: android, .net, json, web-services, wcf-rest

i have json string {"rData":{"details":"abc123|val1|8de92ce|Item 1|val4"} in this format . how to parse the string and get particular value . 
 i have been trying this code but not working .

```
  JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result); 
 JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
 String val1=json_data.getString(1);
```

Comment: one ending brace is missing in your json

Comment: if the question was useful to anyone then please rate it . thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code..

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result); 
  JSONObject childJsonObject = jsonObject.getJsonObject("rData");
  String val = childJsonObject.getString("details");
```

Comment: It is showing a error unterminated object at character .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you missed } at the end of your JSON and this is causing problems while parsing. When you're developing app that genarate/works with JSON you can help with online validators like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).